Intuition behind finite changes notation in Lautrup's continuum mechanics book
The purpose of this post was to solve some doubts about uses of the difference operator in derivations appearing in Lautrup's continuum mechanics book.
As I have understood, the finite change or difference of some quantity is
$$\delta A=A'-A$$
$A'$ being the value of $A$ after some displacement or deformation $\boldsymbol u\to\boldsymbol u+\delta \boldsymbol u$.
This finite change operator can be interchanged with integrals and derivative operator due to their linearity, namely,
$$\delta\, \boldsymbol\nabla A=\boldsymbol\nabla(\delta A)\qquad \&\qquad \delta\, \boldsymbol\nabla\cdot\boldsymbol A=\boldsymbol\nabla\cdot(\delta\boldsymbol A)\qquad \&\qquad\delta\int A=\int\delta A$$
Moreover, it also has a product rule:
$$\delta(AB)=A\,\delta B+B\,\delta A+\delta A\,\delta B$$

$\mathbf{Doubts:}$
$\mathbf{1)}$ For instance, to deduce an expression for a local change in density induced by the change in volume of a material particle, he starts with conservation of mass:
$$\delta(\mathrm dM)=0$$
Since $\mathrm dM=\rho\,\mathrm dV$, he says
$$\delta(\mathrm dM)=\rho\,\delta(\mathrm dV)+\delta\rho\,\mathrm dV=0$$
and so
$$\frac{\delta\rho}{\rho}=-\frac{\delta(\mathrm dV)}{\mathrm dV}=-\boldsymbol\nabla\cdot \boldsymbol u=-\mathrm{Tr}(\bar{\bar{\boldsymbol u}}).$$
Isn't he missing a $\delta\rho\,\delta(\mathrm dV)$ term though?
$\mathbf{2)}$ When taking the difference of the volume of a parallelepiped he does
$$\delta V=\delta(\boldsymbol a\times\boldsymbol b\cdot\boldsymbol c)=\delta\boldsymbol a\times\boldsymbol b\cdot\boldsymbol c+\boldsymbol a\times\delta\boldsymbol b\cdot\boldsymbol c+\boldsymbol a\times\boldsymbol b\cdot\delta\boldsymbol c$$
Is this correct or we need to apply the product rule?
$\mathbf{3)}$ When computing the change in work after a deformation $\boldsymbol u\to\boldsymbol u+\delta \boldsymbol u$  he writes
$$\delta W=\int_V\boldsymbol f\cdot\delta\boldsymbol u\,\mathrm dV+\oint_S(\bar{\bar{\boldsymbol \sigma}}\cdot\delta\boldsymbol u)\cdot\,\mathrm d\boldsymbol S$$
How come the $\delta\boldsymbol u$ appears inside the integrals? Why not
$$\delta W=\boldsymbol f^{\ast}\cdot\delta\boldsymbol u=\left(\int_V\boldsymbol f\,\mathrm dV+\oint_S\bar{\bar{\boldsymbol \sigma}}\cdot\,\mathrm d\boldsymbol S\right)\cdot\delta\boldsymbol u?$$
Is it because $\delta\boldsymbol u$ depends on the variables we integrate with respect to?
$\mathbf{4)}$ At last, he proves that if the stress tensor $\bar{\bar{\boldsymbol \sigma}}$ is symmetric, then
$$\bar{\bar{\boldsymbol \sigma}}:\boldsymbol\nabla\delta\boldsymbol u=\bar{\bar{\boldsymbol \sigma}}:\delta\bar{\bar{\boldsymbol u}}$$
Why is it $\boldsymbol\nabla\delta\boldsymbol u=\delta\bar{\bar{\boldsymbol u}}$, where
$\bar{\bar{\boldsymbol u}}=\dfrac{1}{2}(\boldsymbol\nabla\boldsymbol u+(\boldsymbol\nabla\boldsymbol u)^{\top})?$ Could it be it assumes $\boldsymbol\nabla\boldsymbol u$ is symmetric?

Let's deal with one doubt at a time.

Everything looks fine. Since $\delta dM = 0$ for a close system, as an elementary material volume is, he just writes $dM$ as $dM = \rho dV$, sets its increment equal to zero, to find the relation between $\delta \rho$ and $\delta dV$.

That is the product rule.

He probably starts from (even if he doesn't tell you explicitly) from the differential form of the momentum balance equation that reads
$$\rho D_t \mathbf{v} = \rho \mathbf{g} + \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{\sigma} \ . $$
Then, following a procedure similar to the one used to find the weak form of the equations, he multiplies with a scalar product by an arbitrary vector field, $\delta \mathbf{u}$; among the infinite arbitrary vector fields, you can use the displacement vector field, and thus seen the RHS as an elementary work,
$$\rho \mathbf{g} \cdot \delta \mathbf{u} + \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{\sigma} \cdot \delta \mathbf{u} = \rho \mathbf{g} \cdot \delta \mathbf{u} + \nabla \cdot (\boldsymbol{\sigma} \cdot \delta \mathbf{u}) - \boldsymbol{\sigma} : \nabla \delta \mathbf{u}$$
and integration over the volume $V$ gives
$$\int_V \rho \mathbf{g} \cdot \delta \mathbf{u} - \int_V \boldsymbol{\sigma} : \nabla \delta\mathbf{u} + \oint_{\partial V} \underbrace{\hat{\mathbf{n}} \cdot \boldsymbol{\sigma}}_{\mathbf{t}_n} \cdot \mathbf{u} \ ,$$
having identified the vector stress $\mathbf{t}_n$ on the boundary $\partial V$, using Cauchy relation, $\hat{\mathbf{n}} \cdot \boldsymbol{\sigma} = \mathbf{t}_n$. If $\delta \mathbf{u}$ is the a displacement field, these three terms are the work of volume forces in $V$, the work of internal stress in $V$, the work of stresses on the boundary $\partial V$ respectively.

No, you can't assume that $\nabla \mathbf{u}$ is symmetric.
It is a 2-nd order tensor, and every 2-nd order tensor can be written as the sum of its symmetric and anti-symmetric part,
$$\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{A}^s + \mathbf{A}^a \ ,$$
with
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{A}^s & = \frac{1}{2} ( \mathbf{A} + \mathbf{A}^T ) \\
\mathbf{A}^a & = \frac{1}{2} ( \mathbf{A} - \mathbf{A}^T ) \\
\end{aligned}$$
If $\boldsymbol{\sigma}$ is symmetric, it's possible to prove that
$$\boldsymbol{\sigma} : \mathbf{A} = \boldsymbol{\sigma} : \mathbf{A}^s \ ,$$
since $\boldsymbol{\sigma} : \mathbf{A}^a$ cancels out. To prove it, let's use Cartesian coordinate. $\mathbf{A}^a$ has zero diagonal elements. The result of the product thus reads,
$$\begin{aligned}
 \boldsymbol{\sigma} : \mathbf{A} 
  & = \sigma_{12} A_{12} +  \sigma_{13} A_{13} + \sigma_{23} A_{23} \\
  & + \sigma_{21} A_{21} +  \sigma_{31} A_{31} + \sigma_{32} A_{32} = \\& = \sigma_{12} A_{12} +  \sigma_{13} A_{13} + \sigma_{23} A_{23} \\
  & - \sigma_{12} A_{12} -  \sigma_{13} A_{13} - \sigma_{23} A_{23} = 0
\end{aligned}$$



For $\mathbf{1)}$ it looks as though he neglects crossed terms:
$$\delta(\mathrm dM)=\rho,\delta(\mathrm dV)+\delta\rho,\mathrm dV+\delta\rho,\delta(\mathrm dV)=0\iff \frac{\delta\rho}{\rho}=-\frac{\delta(\mathrm dV)}{\mathrm dV+,\delta(\mathrm dV)}?$$
As for $\mathbf{2)}$, by product rule I meant why are there no crossed terms either such as $\delta a \times \delta b\cdot \delta c$ or $ a \times \delta b\cdot \delta c$, etc.
Nothing to object about $\mathbf{3)}$ nor $\mathbf{4)}$ I think.

linear approximation everywhere in increments. In 1., 2. no term with two or three times "$\delta$"-term

Alright I guess...
